# How to filter a list of Groups that don't contain Companies?

Tags: c#, nhibernate

I'm currently getting a list of Groups as follows:

```
var groups = _session.CreateCriteria<CompanyGroupInfo>()
    //.SetProjection(Projections.ProjectionList()
    //    .Add(LambdaProjection.Count<Company>(c => c.Id) > 0))
    .AddNameSearchCriteria<CompanyGroupInfo>(searchExpression)
    .AddOrder<CompanyGroupInfo>(e => e.Name, Order.Asc)
    .SetMaxResults(pageSize).List<CompanyGroupInfo>();
```

What I'm trying to return is groups, which contains multiple companies

I need to filter this list so that I don't return any group that doesn't contain any companies. I was hoping I could do something similar to what's commented out, but that doesn't work. I'm pretty new to NHibernate, so this is probably a really simple issue. Unfortunately, I don't know what to do! Could somebody please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like:

```
.Add(Restrictions.IsNotEmpty("Companies"))
```

The converse of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/942905/nhibernate-criteria-expression-to-retrieve-all-entities-with-null-count-child-co).